# Ошибка с указателями в Си

Tags: c, указатели, адрес

Сейчас разбираюсь с указателями в си, и немного не понимаю один момент. Этот момент начинается на строке `m += 1; // Сдвиг вправо на 8 байт` (предпоследний абзац). Почему-то после вычисления `*m = (float) *a - n + (int) *x;` адрес m меняется на 0x3fd3333300000000. У меня в XCode выдает ошибку EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT). При `m += 2` такой ошибки нет, все вычисляется верно, и адрес m равен 0x7ffeefbff4d8. Как можно объяснить эту ошибку?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  // Объявление переменных
  char * p, c; // p - указатель типа char*, c - переменная типа char
  int * a, b; // a - указатель типа int*, b - переменная типа int
  float *x, y = 3.5; // x - указатель типа float*, y - переменная типа float
  double *m, n; // m - указатель типа double*, n - переманная типа double

  printf ("Адреса всех переменных \n *p=%p \t c=%p \n *a=%p \t b=%p \n *x=%p \t y=%p \n *m=%p \t n=%p \n\n" , &p, &c, &a, &b, &x, &y, &m, &n);

  a = &b; // Указателю a присваивается адрес переменной b
  printf("Введите b = ");
  scanf("%d", &b); //scanf("%d", a);

  printf(" a = %p \t *a = %d \t b = %d \n", a, *a, b); // Указателю a присваивается числовое значение адреса b, выводит b с помощью указателя и операции разыменования

  p = a; // Указателю p присваиваем адрес указателя a
  c = *p; // Переменной с приравниваем значение хранимое по адресу р
  *p = *(p + 3); // Значению хранимому в р присваивается значение хранимое по адресу (р + 3)
  *(p + 3) = c; // Значению хранимому по адресу р + 3 присваивается значение с
  printf(" p = %p \t c = %d \t a = %p \t b = %d\n", p, c, a, b);

  x = &y; // Указателю x присваивается адрес переменной y
  printf(" x = %p \t *x = %f \t y = %f\n", x, *x, y);

  a = x; // Указателю а присваиваем адрес хранимый в указателе х
  *a = *x; // Значению по адресу хранимому в указателе a присваиваем значение по адресу хранимому в указателе х
  printf(" a = %p \t *a = %d \t x = %p \t *x = %f \t y = %f\n", a, *a, x, *x, y);

  a = &b;
  y = 12345.6789;
  printf(" x = %p \t *x = %f \t y = %f\n", x, *x, y);

  p = x; // Присваиваем указателю р типа char значение указателя х типа float
  c = *p; // Переменной с присваиваем значение хранимое по адресу в p
  *p = *(p + 3); // Значению хранимому по адресу в р присваиваеваем значение хранимое в р + 3 (на 3 байта больше чем в р)
  *(p + 3) = c; // значению р + 3 (на 3 байта больше чем в р) присваиваем значение с
  printf(" p = %p \t c = %d \t x = %p \t y = %f\n", p, c, x, y);

  m = &n; //адрес n присваиваем в m
  printf(" m = %p \t *m = %lf \t n = %lf\n", m, *m, n);

  n = 5.5; // *m = 5.5, n = 5.5
  printf(" m = %p \t *m = %lf \t n = %lf\n", m, *m, n);

  b = n = y = 1.7; // y = 1.7, n = 1.7, b = 1.7, *m = 1.7
  printf (" b = %d \t y = %f \t n = %lf\n", b, y, n);
  printf(" *a = %d \t *x = %f \t *m = %lf\n", *a, *x, *m);



  m += 1; // Сдвиг вправо на 8 байт
  printf(" n = %lf \t &n = %p \t m = %p\n", n, &n, m); // Тут m = 0x7ffeefbff4b8 

  *m = (float) *a - n + (int) *x;
  printf(" m = %p\n", m); // Адрес почему-то изменяется, в моем случае он становится - 0x3fd3333300000000, что по идее не может быть
  printf(" m = %p \t *m = %lf\n", m, *m); // Тут уже выводит ошибку так как не получается получить значение по адресу 0x3fd3333300000000
  printf("Значения переменных \n *p=%p \t c=%d \n *a=%p \t b=%d \n *x=%p \t y=%f \n *m=%p \t n=%lf\n", p, c, a, b, x, y, m, n);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Язык С не допускает присваиваний `p = a;`, `a = x;`, `p = x;` и т.п. Типы указателей не совпадают.  В остальном: неопределенное поведение есть неопределенное поведение. Никаких других объяснений тут нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы сдвинули указатель, указывавший на адрес в стеке, на восемь байтов (куда он теперь указывает?) и записали туда какое-то число. Стек испорчен, последствия непредсказуемые, все пропало.

Comment: Почему при сдвиге на 16 байт ошибки нет? Или это воля случая, и все зависит только от того что лежало по тому адресу?

Comment: @DanilLyamkin "последствия непредсказуемые"